# Passing locationID along with location name in Autocomplete TextBox in MVC3 using JSon

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, autocomplete

I have masters for Country,State.....
I made autocomplete text box for location.
This autocomplete returns all locations names from these masters(All country name and State Names).
**All i passing to jquery is location names in the form of string.
I want to pass both location Id and  Location Name to jquery,But want to show only location names in Autocomplete.**
As this autocomplete is to used for storing preffered Location from users.
**I need the id alond with respective location name to store user prefferd loaction information in user table.**

Please suggest how can i do this....
A demo will be more useful.....

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using JqueryUI for autocomplete.  JqueryUI's Autocomplete will, by default, work w/ json objects -- more specifically an array of object literals w/ the properties: "label" and "value";

```
{ label:x, value:y }
```

The autocomplete will use the "label" property to calculate the autocomplete match and when selected by the user, will use the "value" property as the selected item.  Furthermore, if the "value" property is omitted, "label" will be used for both comparison and selection.

The important thing to note is that you're not limited to those properties.  You can, for example, add additional properties such as ..say .."location_id".

```
{ label: "Some State and Country", location_id: 2 }
```

Using the autocomplete event "select", you can take some action ie store the selected location_id to a hidden input to be posted by a form or even fire a whiz-bang ajax call.  Try this:

```
...
<form>
Locations: <input id="location" />

<input type="hidden" id="location_id" />
<input type="submit">
</form>
...

<script>
  var mylocations = [
      {
        label: "North Carolina, USA",
        id: 123
      },
      {
        label: "North Dakota, USA",
        id: 128
      },
      {
        label: "Nevada, USA",
        id: 125
      },
      {
        label: "New York, USA",
        id: 311
      },
      {
        label: "New Brunswick, Canada",
        id: 267
      },
      {
        label: "Nova Scotia, Canada",
        id: 235
      },
      {
        label: "Newfoundlandand , Canada",
        id: 223
      }];

  $("#location").autocomplete({
    source: mylocations,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
      // store your location id somewhere like a hidden input ..you
      // can then allow the user to post the form (and selected id) back. 
      $( "#location_id" ).val( ui.item.id );
      return false;
    }
  });
</script>
```